# parallel stream not using custom forkjoinpool

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-stream, fork-join

I have a parallel stream like this:

```
mylist.stream().parallel().map(transform::docPDFTypeToItem)
.map(fdUtil::createEdiLine).forEach(document::add)
```

this is working on my two CPUs

now I'm trying to oversize the forkjoinpool because I have a lot of IO as described [here](https://blog.krecan.net/2014/03/18/how-to-specify-thread-pool-for-java-8-parallel-streams/):

```
new ForkJoinPool(20).submit(() -> 
    mylist.stream().parallel().map(transform::docPDFTypeToItem)
    .map(fdUtil::createEdiLine).parallel().forEach(document::add)).get())
```

but this is not working well, as I have only 5 threads used:

```
08:54:48.423 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-18] 
08:54:48.426 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-25] 
08:54:48.427 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29] 
08:54:48.430 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15] 
08:54:48.431 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11] 
08:54:50.426 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-25] 
08:54:50.427 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29]
08:54:48.423 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-18] 
08:54:48.426 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-25] 
08:54:48.427 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29] 
08:54:48.430 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-15] 
08:54:48.431 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-11] 
08:54:50.426 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-25] 
08:54:50.427 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-29]
...
```

If I use

```
 System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", "20");
```

it is working as expected (20 threads reused).

Do you know what's wrong? Does this `.submit()` sound like a hack?

I know I could use `completableFuture` like [here](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.fr/2016/06/java-8-completablefuture-vs-parallel.html) but I think it is less readable.

Comment: So it seems that it is not a good idea to use a forkJoinpool as a wrapper for this.